# How to create a trigger that automatically generates a primary key from multiple fields

Tags: sql, pgadmin

I have a geospatial db with (a.o.) a table with locations, and a table with features. The primary key for the locations table is location_id. Location_id is also a foreign key in the features table. The features table also includes the fields "type" (in which a two-letter code is entered to denote particular types of features), and N (which differentiates the different features that may be linked to one location). I figured a combination of location_id, type, and N would make a decent primary key for the features table. Previously, I entered these ids manually. However, I would like for this to be automatically done when a "user" enters a location ID, N, and type. (Ideally I want to find a way to automatically generate the correct N, so that "users" need only enter location_id and type, but I think this should be posted as a separate question?).

I have been trying to achieve this via triggers (see code below), but when I test it by trying to add a new data row to my features table, I get the error message "duplicate key value violates unique constraint features_pkey". Could someone point me in the direction of help for this issue?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_features_id()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    compos_id text;
BEGIN
    SELECT loc_id ||  type  || N FROM features INTO compos_id;
    NEW.id := compos_id;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS set_lf_id_trigger on public.landscape_features_point;

CREATE TRIGGER set_features_id_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON "features"
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_features_id();
```

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: … See the [help] for more on [how to ask good questions](/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topics. See also the [tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).